# Angular database without a server

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

I am working on an assignment for a dummy phonebook app, which is an "extra points" part of a test for a local frontend job opening. I did some basic apps with angular before, but I always used it along with php and mysql. For this project the requirements state that I can't communicate with a server, so I need to store, edit, delete and search through data without a real database.

I don't even know what options are out there to achieve something like that, neither which one should I choose. I am looking for a simplest tool that could help me achieve those requirements,  preferably one that has decent documentation that can help me get up and running as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple local filesystem and store objects as JSON using `JSON.stringify()` and parse them back using `JSON.parse(jsonstring)`

to write phonebook to your server's file

```
var phonebook = {
    'name1' : 234283409,
    'name2' : 234253453,
    'name3' : 234234236
};

var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(phonebook);

/*
__________________
contents of jsonStr

{"name1":234283409,"name2":234253453,"name3":234234236}
__________________
write a logic here to save this JSON on a file in your server.
*/
```

to read phonebook to your server's file

```
//write a logic here to read JSON back from your server's file
var jsonStr = getJSONDataFromServer();

var phonebook = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

//now you can use your phonebook as a usual js object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use csv file to store your data.

Answer (score 1):

To store data on the client you can use any local storage methods:

- [WebStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API): Web Storage API (provides both *sessionStorage* and *localStorage*)
- [gears](https://developers.google.com/gears/): Google Gears-based persistent storage
- [whatwg db](https://html.spec.whatwg.org): HTML database storage standard
- [cookie](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265): Cookie-based persistent storage RFC

The best choice depends on the kind of data you need to store, and the usage of that data. The most common choice is `WebStorage`.

If you use Angular, the great module [ngStorage](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage) is available, that makes Web Storage working in the *Angular Way*.

Be warned that:

- you'll be able to store only data *per user*, of course (i.e., you'll not be able to store any global status of the application).
- any client storage solution poses strict space limits, which often differ from browser to browser.

If instead you simply don't want to use any *local* server solution, you could try some cloud platform, like, for example, [firebase](https://developers.google.com/gears/) (just acquired by Google), or others.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I started working on it using ngStorage, but I am wondering will all of the functionality I need be possible with this approach. I will need to add an id key to every contact, and I'll need an option to display and edit each of the contacts in a separate view based on their id, and I will also need an option to search for specific names or numbers.

Comment: If you need to add an uniq id key to every contact, you really need a server side backend... :-) Please read about firebase...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Google's Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). If firebase is complicated to you then use simple localstorage.